# Firefox is not showing float numbers

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show a float number as a float but in firefox and safari it converts to an integer but on chrome, it shows as a float number.
I don't know how it's happening?

```
const TableSection = React.memo(({ query, isOpen }) => {
  const { runtime } = useData(query);

    return (
          <>
            <p className="text-primary-dark">
              Query took: <span className="font-bold">{`${runtime.toFixed(2)} ms`}</span>
            </p>
    </>
  );
});
```

```
    let t0 = performance.now(); //start time
    fetchData(tableName);
    let t1 = performance.now(); //end time
    setRuntime(t1 - t0);
```

fetchData function

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = (tableName) => {
      setData([]);
      const name = TABLE_NAMES.find((name) => name === tableName);
      if (name) {
        setError(false);
        fetch(getURL(tableName))
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
              return res.text();
            } else {
              throw new Error("Something went wrong");
            }
          })
          .then((data) => convertToJson(data))
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        setError(true);
        toast.error("Please enter a valid query");
      }
    };
    let t0 = performance.now(); //start time
    fetchData(tableName);
    let t1 = performance.now(); //end time
    setRuntime(t1 - t0);
  }, [tableName]);
```

Comment: None of that code will show the the number to the user. Please post **that** code.

Comment: please check I updated the code

Comment: What does `fetchData` do? If it's an asynchronous function then it will complete _instantly_ and your `t1 - t0` value will be zero. You need to either `await` it, or set `t1 = performance.now()` in the `then()` continuation.

Comment: Also post the definition of `setRuntime`.

Comment: setRuntime is a defined as   const [runtime, setRuntime] = useState("");

Comment: everything works fine in chrome

Comment: I added a fetchData code as well, please check